# How to protect origin server?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, web, cloudflare

I have an AWS EC2 as origin web server, and cloudflare in front of it. And I cached all static files in Cloudflare, but still there are many static files access logs in log files.

Is it possible to find out origin behind CloudFlare?

```
 CloudFlare  (cname => AWS ELB, www.example.com => myweb.elb-domain.com )
=> ELB  (:80 => origin-ip:8080)
=> Origin server (:8080)
```

Normally, how much would people know about my web server?

Answer (score 3):

The IP address that accessed your site is passed in CloudFlare's own `CF-Connecting-IP` header. You should always use this instead of `X-Forwarded-For`, as that can be supplied by the user and contain untrustworthy information.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare passes an X-Forwarded-For http header with its requests to your origin server, giving the original IP address of the requester. You can log that header at your end if you want to.